# Autolayout not working with reusable tableview cells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, tableview, autolayout

I'm trying to use Autolayout and Interface Builder to create a custom TableViewCell. I setup my cell in viewDidLoad like this:

```
[tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BChatCell" bundle:Nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ChatCell"];
```

Then I dequeue the cell like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView_ cellForRowAtIndexPath:        (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BChatCell * cell = [tableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChatCell"];
    return cell;
}
```

When the table view first loads it loads correctly:

[image]

However, after the table scrolls, Autolayout breaks:

[image]

Here are the constraints:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to show more of your constraints, maybe check if you set the `translateAutoResizeMaskToConstraints` to NO.

Comment: I tried turning off auto-resize mask but it just completely breaks autolayout.

Comment: Constraints looks good to me, anything spacial in `BChatCell`?

Comment: Did anyone find out something about this? I'm running into it now and couldn't find a solution.

Comment: So far I've not found a solution. I'm just laying out my cells using frames.

Comment: @BenSmiley Have a you found the solution for this? You can have a look at my answer as well.

Comment: @BenSmiley - First thing you need to remember that once you start using autolayout then you should not set frames or else you will get wiered results. I have tried your problem by creating sample demo - Try this approaches 1) Just remove all constraints and its working fine 2) Even after applying my cell UI does not get messed up

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue. Drove me crazy because everything looks great until the cells get reused.

I discovered that the view that was getting resized was not the cell itself (which is always screen width), but an inner content view I had. You're able to print all the constraints on any view with `NSLog(@"%@", [theView constraints]);` which helped with debugging

Also tried to no avail:

- setting all the important views and subviews to `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO`
- manually setting bounds inside `-(void)prepareForReuse`
- calling `setNeedsUpdateConstraints`

The issue was that I had named my inner card view `"contentView"` which is already a named view in `UITableViewCell`. Changing it fixed the resizing issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is the static leading and trailing. Your trailing constant is 200 and when you rotate it you want it to become more than that 200 (because of the width of the screen). This breaks the constraint and probably in the console is saying that you have ambiguity in your constraints and it did the automatically add a new one (which results in weird behavior).

- So what I suggest is that to try making the trailing constraint **Greater than or equal 200** and see if it works.
- Another solution would be adding a width constraint for that blue view and removing the trailing constraint.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This isn't a problem when the screen is rotated. The problem happens when the table is scrolled. Also, if I did rotate the screen, the expected behavior would be that the blue square expanded. I don't how it could break the constraints?

Comment: That's really strange. Were there any console errors after rotation? usually when something goes wrong it would throw some type of exception and handles it (in a bad way).

Comment: Hi Sami, if you take a closer look at the original question, this isn't a problem with screen rotation. It's a problem with cells losing their constraints when they're re-used. There weren't any error messages.

Comment: @BenSmiley try this [cell setNeedsLayout:YES]; in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: before returning it.